# how to adapt a dimension with an integer when setting attributes in android?

Tags: android

I've been making a custom view.
So I need to set a dp or wrap_content(match_parent).
But I found I can't set a dp and wrap_content together.
Is there any way to set them together?
I tried this way, but not working.
when I set
 `app:buttonWidth="100dp"` it's working, but not working when
`app:buttonWidth="wrap_content"`

*xml*

```
    <com.example.custom.ButtonLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:buttonWidth="100dp"
        app:buttonHeight="100dp"/>
```

*attr*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="ButtonStyle">
        <attr name="buttonWidth" format="dimension|integer">
            <enum name="match_parent" value="-1"/>
            <enum name="wrap_content" value="-2"/>
        </attr>
        <attr name="buttonHeight" format="dimension|integer">
            <enum name="match_parent" value="-1"/>
            <enum name="wrap_content" value="-2"/>
        </attr>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

*CustomView class*

```
  init{
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.button_layout, this, true)
        attrs?.apply {
            val typedArray =
                context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ButtonStyle, defStyle, 0)
          
            buttonWidth =  typedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.ButtonStyle_buttonWidth,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
            buttonHeight =  typedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.ButtonStyle_buttonHeight,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)

            typedArray.recycle()
        }


    }
```

Comment: what for do you need that? why not set min width?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. I want to set the wrap_content. 100dp is working, but wrap_content is not working.

Comment: you can set wrap_content in xml to your layout(button or whatever) and set also min width 100dp to same layout

Comment: `buttonWidth =  typedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.ButtonStyle_buttonWidth,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)`  this is not working when I set wrap_content.Do  you understand my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did not get what you want first,
let me show some code for you:

```
    public FooterBar(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
    
            TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                    R.styleable.FooterBar, 0, 0);
            String btnSavetitle = a.getString(R.styleable.FooterBar_saveButtonText);
            boolean cameraVisible = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.FooterBar_secondButtonVisible, false);
            int secondIconButton = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.FooterBar_secondIconButton, R.drawable.ic_baseline_wallpaper_48);
 int width = a.getLayoutDimension(R.styleable.FooterBar_widthSize, -2);
    
            setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.form_footer_bar, this, true);
    
            btnSave = findViewById(R.id.footer_bar_save);
            ivSecondButton = findViewById(R.id.footer_bar_second_button);
            setSecondIconButton(secondIconButton);
     if (width > 0) {
            ivSecondButton.getLayoutParams().width = width;
        }
            btnSave.setText(btnSavetitle);
            ivSecondButton.setVisibility(cameraVisible ? ImageView.VISIBLE : ImageView.GONE);
    
            a.recycle();
        }
```

The main idea is to pass value from typedArray to button object you defined in your custom view class via setWidth(). -2 is for wrap content
EDIT:
in attr.xml:

```
<attr name="widthSize" format="dimension">
        <enum name="fill_parent" value="-1" />
        <enum name="match_parent" value="-1" />
        <enum name="wrap_content" value="-2" />
    </attr>
```

in Custom View code all I do:

```
 if (width > 0) { ivSecondButton.getLayoutParams().width = width; }
```

in layout xml:

```
<com.mobnius.core.ui.component.FooterBar
        android:id="@+id/form_footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:widthSize="wrap_content" //or 50dp for example
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:saveButtonText="@string/save"
        app:secondButtonVisible="true"
        app:secondIconButton="@drawable/ic_baseline_wallpaper_48" />
```

Comment: your answer is not matched with my problem. I know the wrap_content is -2, and match_parent is -1. So I added that in attr.xml as you can see. the error is occured in `buttonWidth =  typedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.ButtonStyle_buttonWidth,                 ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)`

Comment: look, what I see is that you don't define your button and don't pass buttonWidth like button.setWidth(buttonWidth)

Comment: my button is defined below my init code. buttonWidth is adapted to button like this `            button.measure(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
`

Comment: I think measure method is not what you need to set your button width to wrap_content

Comment: please try this code `buttonWidth =  typedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.ButtonStyle_buttonWidth,                 ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)` and `<attr name="buttonHeight" format="dimension|integer">
            <enum name="match_parent" value="-1"/>
            <enum name="wrap_content" value="-2"/>
        </attr>` in your project. you are not understanding my question now

Comment: I edited my answer. Have tested this code - works jast fine.

Comment: I've got this error. `Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert value at index 1 to dimension: type=0x10
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize` I don't understnad why code is not working

Comment: sorry, copy paste error. just remove |integer from attr format. After that you will need to rebuild your project probably. Don't forget to add dp if you set numeric size in layout xml.

Comment: I removed that `|integer` but got the same error.

Comment: Got it! change this - a.getDimensionPixelSize to a.getLayoutDimension and it will work. Tested both on emulator and real device.

Comment: the first time I saw the question, I didn't think that the solution would take more than a couple of minutes)